# Application Form in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, webforms

My company uses the Genesis Framework and WordPress for the overall website.  It's a multi-site set up and we'll have multiple child themes in Genesis.

I need to create a multi-page application form with user-sign-up (WP-MU?) that will allow a user to register, complete the app and be able to quit and return to their stopping point.

I'm looking for ideas on where to begin.  I've gone in and created my own version of the 'page' template, so I can create the form from that.  I've taken out the loop function and began writing my own custom code to replace it.

I normally use PHP frameworks for this sort of thing, making CRUD much simpler for me, but working inside of WP has me a bit lost.  Anyone care to offer up a bit of advice?  Need more info?  I'll edit the post if so.  Thanks!

Comment: Maybe I didn't really understand what Genesis is/does. I just found a lot of buzzwords on their website. Seems like an overclocked WP-theme. But the latest WP (3.x) has multi-page support included and registration should work for every single page (and also return an user to that page). You don't need WPµ anymore. Years ago on WPµ I created a theme for the signup-page (signup.php) as well as an overrided [signup_user-function](http://codex.wordpress.org/WPMU_Functions/wpmu_signup_user) to add the user to different blogs, once the registration is completed.

Comment: Well, i was really trying to create a multi-page form.  Genesis is exactly as you said...just an amped up theme so I duplicated the 'page' template and cut out the normal loop.  Then I added my own hook to pull in the content based on where the user was in the form.

I sort of wanted to know if there were any best practices other than using someone else's plugin.  Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer...in case anyone else needed help with this...turned out to be as simple as creating a custom page-template, replacing the loop with a hook to your own function and handling all of the requests by parsing the url.  this worked for me, but not well enough to stay with WP, so I wrote the application in an MVC framework.